# Why does Git give "Unknown command: pick" during an interactive rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I did:

```
git rebase mybranch --interactive
```

And I edited my rebase-todo file to something like this:

```
pick aec2c2b Add foo method to bar
edit 8441f4b Do something slightly wrong
pick dabcc80 Do something else correctly
```

But when I told Git to make it happen, I got:

```
Unknown command: ﻿pick aec2c2b8f9c314f9dddc67a2c71f8be0a27c0fab Add foo method to bar
Please fix this using 'git rebase --edit-todo'.
```

What? But `pick` is a valid command!

Why did this happen, and how can I fix it?

Output of `git --version`:

```
git version 2.8.1.windows.1
```

I'm running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I collaborate with developers who use Visual Studio, I have my editor configured to save files as UTF-8 with BOM. Git doesn't know what to do with BOMs, so that is why I got the error. (Git thinks I tried to use the command `BOMpick` instead of `pick`. You can detect the BOM in the error message I included in my question.)

Removing the BOM fixed the error. Specifically, I added this to my `.editorconfig`:

```
[.git/**]
charset = utf-8
```

Because at the top of the file it already had this:

```
[*]
charset = utf-8-bom
```