# Why does Gitolite give 'invalid repo name' on clone?

Tags: git, git-bash, gitolite, non-printing-characters

I'm trying to clone a repo from my server running Gitolite, but it's giving me an error:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@git.example.com:1234/users/me/foo
Cloning into 'foo'...
FATAL: invalid repo name: 'users/me/foo'
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, I know the repo exists, because `ssh -p 1234 git@git.example.com info` gives:

```
hello me, this is git@git.example.com running gitolite3 v3.6-16-g4fefd3f on git 1.7.10.4

 R W    users/me/foo
```

I even copy/pasted the name of the repo from that output, so I know I didn't misspell it.

I'm doing this from Git Bash on Windows 8.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was [hit by non-printing characters again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39401435/2747593).

As can be detected in my question, there is some non-printing character (which I haven't been able to identify) immediately before `users`, which causes the error.

After removing it, I was able to clone the repo successfully.